# screen with top banner, webview and bottom banner

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to create a very simple android screen with the following content: top banner, webview and bottom banner. for some reason, i can't do it. my xml look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/FrameLayout02"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:isScrollContainer="false">


    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_above="@+id/Web"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"></ImageView>


    <WebView android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/Web" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></WebView>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/Web"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"></ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

what is wrong?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer all is wrong. Your code is a mess.

Long answer. You are trying to have an `ImageView` above a `WebView` and at the bottom another `ImageView`. I'm not exactly sure what of the mistakes broke it but that's also not important. Take a look at my example XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/topimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/bottomimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
    <WebView android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/topimage"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomimage"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now what my XML does is simple. It uses a `RelativeLayout` as a container to allow a more flexible child alignment. The `ImageView` called `topimage` will adjust its height to its content and fill the parent in width. It is aligned to its parents top. The second `ImageView` is similar with the only exception that it is pinned to its parents bottom. The `WebView` is aligned in between both `ImageView`s. It adjust it's height to the 'ImageView`s heights.

Try to always keep some kind of structure in your XML and also Java code so you and also others can throw a look at it without starting to cry.