# Put ImageView over WebView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Does anyone has an idea about how to put a ImageView over WebView ? here is an example

[image]

Comment: This can help <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192867/screen-with-top-banner-webview-and-bottom-banner>